# Changing last 5 char of array

Tags: c++

I have a program that encrypts files, but adds the extension ".safe" to the end. So the end result is something like "file.txt.safe"

When I go to decrypt the file, the user enters the file name again: "file.txt.safe" which is saved to a char. Now I want to remove ".safe" and rename the file to its original name.

I have tried the following, but nothing seems to happen and there are no errors.

```
Decrypt (myFile); //decrypts myFile

char * tmp = myFile;
char * newFile;
newFile = strstr (tmp,".safe");  //search tmp for ".safe"
strncpy (newFile,"",5);   //replace .safe with ""

rename (myFile, newFile);
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but if this approach doesn't work, I'm looking for any simple method.

**Edited to add:**
*(copied by moderator from poster's response to K-ballo)*

Thanks everyone. I took the std::string approach and found this to work:

```
Decrypt(myFile); 
string str = myFile; 
size_t pos = str.find(".safe"); 
str.replace(pos,5,""); 
rename(myFile, str.c_str());
```

Comment: The simplest method would be to use `std::string`. It has both a `find` and `replace`. I suppose you could just put a null where the '.' is though to solve the immediate problem. Using C++ alternatives will greatly benefit you later, however.

Comment: try moving the pointer forward the length of ".safe" `strncpy (tmp+5,"",5);`

Comment: This seems to be more of a `C` question, rather than `C++`. However, I concur with others recommending `C++`'s `std::string`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what you want to do, simply changing the `strncpy` line to this will work:

```
*newFile = '\0';
```

This would still have problems if the filename contains an early *.safe* (like in *file.safest.txt.safe*), or if it does not contain the substring *.safe* at all. You would be better of searching from the end of the array, and making sure you do find something.

This seems like a better approach (although in *C++* it would be better to just go with `std::string`):

```
char* filename = ...;
size_t filename_length = strlen( filename );
int safe_ext_pos = filename_length - 5; // 5 == length of ".safe"
if( safe_ext_pos > 0 && strcmp( ".safe", filename + safe_ext_pos ) == 0 )
    filename[ safe_ext_pos ] = '\0';
```

This is the `std::string` version of the code:

```
std::string filename = ...;
int safe_ext_pos = filename.length() - 5; // 5 == length of ".safe"
if( safe_ext_pos > 0 && filename.compare( safe_ext_pos, 5, ".safe" ) == 0 )
    filename.erase( safe_ext_pos );
```

Comment: And guess what has a `find_last_of` :p

Comment: @chris: I would use `std::string` if it was me, but I still wouldn't _find_ for something that can only be at a particular location...

Comment: @chris: Feel free to edit my answer to provide an `std::string` alternative, but make sure to maintain efficiency. Note how there are no string copies done in the code (i.e., don't use `substr`).

Comment: Your comparison is flawed. `size_ext_pos > 0` will be true even for strings shorter than five characters. You should first check that `filename_length > 5` as your code will fail horribly for filenames shorter than five characters.

Comment: @eq: Damn unsigned arithmetics, you are right about that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @K-ballo, would you fancy something like `std::string::erase`, seeing as how that's all that's being done here?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I took the std::string approach and found this to work:

    `Decrypt(myFile);

    string str = myFile;
    size_t pos = str.find(".safe");
    str.replace(pos,5,"");
   
    rename(myFile, str.c_str());`

Comment: @JamesCarr, clicking the accept button (checkmark) will let others know the answer was the one that helped solve your problem.

Comment: Done. Thanks Chris and K-ballo

Comment: @chris: I was actually thinking about the comparison of the trailing substring _".safe"_, in a way that can be easily mixed with the string literal ".safe" itself...

Comment: @K-ballo, How about an `assert` that makes sure of the length and extension (using `compare()`), and then `erase()`ing the extension?

Comment: @chris: `compare()` seems to be exactly what I was after, I will add that `std::string` example now.

Comment: @James Carr: See the updated answer for a `std::string` version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should take care:

```
my.safe.file.txt.safe
```

Instead of just searching for '.safe' and removing it or truncating the filename at the first one, you should ensure that it's actually at the end of the string:

```
std::string myfile = ...
Decrypt(myFile);

const std::string extension_to_remove = ".safe";
if (decryption is successful &&
    myfile.size() >= extension_to_remove.size() &&
    myfile.substr(myfile.size()-5) == extension_to_remove)
{
  std::string newFile = myfile.substr(0, myfile.size()-5);
  rename(myFile, newFile);
}
```

---

Also a note on filename extensions. It's really a pretty awful practice for software to identify file types using a special format in the filename.* It's fine for humans to organize their files with special naming conventions, but software should by and large be oblivious to it, except perhaps to make it easy for humans to use the conventions they want.

So your code for decrypting a file shouldn't be doing this task. Instead your decryption code should take a file to decrypt and a file to contain the output. Then your code for computing the output filename from the encrypted file's name should exist somewhere else, such as in the user interface where the user tells you the output filename. Your code would remove '.safe' if it exists and supply the modified name as the default output filename, to be confirmed by the user.

```
void perform_decryption(std::string const &encrypted, std::string const &decrypted) {
    Decrypt(encrypted);
    if (decryption is successful && encrypted!=decrypted)
        rename(encrypted, decrypted);
}

std::string default_decrypted_name(std::string const &filename) {
    const std::string extension_to_remove = ".safe";
    if (filename.size() >= extension_to_remove.size() &&
        filename.substr(filename.size()-extension_to_remove.size()) == extension_to_remove)
    {
      return filename.substr(0, filename.size()-extension_to_remove.size());
    }
    return filename + ".decrypted";
}
```

<sub>* here are some reasons against filename extensions:</sub>

- <sub>filename extensions are not unique, in some circumstances causing conflicts where a file's type cannot be positively identified. (the fact that they can't even perform their intended purpose really ought to be enough...)</sub>
- <sub>It degrades the usability of the filename for organizing. When 'myfile.txt' is renamed to 'myfile.txt.old' it's no longer seen as a text file.</sub>
- <sub>It's caused security issues because fake type metadata can be mistaken for real type metadata when the real type metadata is hidden.</sub>
- <sub>[and more...](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2005/04/macosx-10-4/11/)</sub>